# asp.net core 2 exception not showing where the issue is

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, stack-trace, asp.net-core-middleware

I have an asp.net coree 2 web application. I user a middleware filter because it is a multi tenant application.

```
app.UseMiddleware<TenantMiddleware>();
```

And in the middleware

```
public class TenantMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public TenantMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) 
    { 
        ... 
        await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I have an Exception, the stack trace always refers to the middleware instead of showing me where the problem is. If I remove the middleware the exception trace tells me the exact line where the exception occurs, but with the middle ware it is always the same trace:

The first line is the one that changes and shows the real problem, this is fine:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

But the stack trace is meaningless

```
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MiddlewareFilterBuilder+<>c+<<BuildPipeline>b__8_0>d.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
MyWebApp.Web.AppConfig.TenantMiddleware+<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext() in Tenant.cs
+
            await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Always show the Tenent Middleware instead the line of the page where the error ocurrs

```
MyWebApp.Web.AppConfig.TenantMiddleware+<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext() in Tenant.cs
+
            await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
```

Is there a way to have the stack trace referred to the page where the error happens?

Thanks.

UPDATE

Thanks to Tao's answer I came up with a possible cause.

The problem is in the Startup.cs, in the COnfigureServices:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new MiddlewareFilterAttribute(typeof(LocalizationPipeline)));
});
```

And the LocalizationPipeline:

```
public class LocalizationPipeline
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder appBuilder, RequestLocalizationOptions options)
    {
        appBuilder.UseRequestLocalization(options);
    }
}
```

The trace, when I remove that line, looks like:

```
DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
MyWebApp.Web.Controllers.TestController.Index() in TestController.cs
+
            var c = b / a;
lambda_method(Closure , object , Object[] )
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(object target, Object[] parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
MyWebApp.Web.AppConfig.TenantMiddleware+<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext() in Tenant.cs
+
            await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Any idea of why this is removing all the info from the trace? Any possible solution?

Comment: Yes, TenantMiddleware has a proper constructor. I have updated my question. Also the middleware is working fine. The only problem I have is when I have an error in a controller or view the trace always refers to the middleware, so I can't see where the error is...

Comment: What is the detail steps to reproduce your issue? I made a test with new asp.net core project, create `TenantMiddleware` and throw exception in `HomeController`, I could get exception `CoreApp.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in HomeController.cs, line 23` in the right line.

Comment: Thanks Tao, you gave me an idea of what can be. The problem is in the Startup.cs, in the ConfigureServices.   services.AddMvc(options => {             options.Filters.Add(new MiddlewareFilterAttribute(typeof(LocalizationPipeline))); }); If I remove that line it works and shows the error....I have updated my question with all the code

Comment: This is a bug, and check this [MiddlewareFilter exception not meaningful #6596](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6596#issuecomment-330876391)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue, it is caused by `MiddlewareFilterBuilder`.

For `Asp.Net Core 2.0` project, the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` is `Version 2.0.4` which has this bug. This issue has been fixed by `Version 2.1.0` by adding `resourceExecutedContext.ExceptionDispatchInfo?.Throw();.`

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/d46948da1d4709bcb8ae0094074a307ece636b4d/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/MiddlewareFilterBuilder.cs#L83).

Solution:

Try to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` with `Version 2.1.2` from Nuget window.

**WorkAround**

Custom Implemention of `MiddlewareFilterBuilder`.

1. Add [MiddlewareFilter](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a67d9363e22be8ef63a1a62539991e1da3a6e30e/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/MiddlewareFilter.cs)
2. Add [MiddlewareFilterAttribute](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a67d9363e22be8ef63a1a62539991e1da3a6e30e/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Filters/MiddlewareFilterAttribute.cs)
3. Add [MiddlewareFilterBuilder](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/d46948da1d4709bcb8ae0094074a307ece636b4d/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/MiddlewareFilterBuilder.cs#L83)
4. Add [MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/f12f9b46ed5cc848a36db1fa9933c35b3eb60351/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.cs)
5. Modify `Startup.cs` `ConfigureService`

   ```
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddMvc(options =>
       {
           options.Filters.Add(new MiddlewareFilterAttribute(typeof(LocalizationPipeline)));
       });
       services.AddSingleton<RequestLocalizationOptions>();
       services.AddSingleton<MiddlewareFilterBuilder>();
       services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IStartupFilter, MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter>());
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, it is what I imagine after reading a lot about it. The problem is MySQL is not working properly in 2.1 yet...

Comment: @JohnMathison If so, you could try the [workaround](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6596#issuecomment-330876391) to implement your own `MiddlewareFilterBuilder`. There is some code link missing in the github issue, you could check the source code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Tao, but one of the links is broken, don't you have an example of how to create your own MiddlewareFilterBuilder?

Comment: Thanks so much, it works, and at least for now no side effects. The only line I need to remove in order to work is services.AddSingleton<RequestLocalizationOptions>(); since I have created my own translation system, and I load the pages from database, so users can change their page names...but now I do have back the trace on errors, which is great.

Comment: @JohnMathison One more point, I am not sure whether you make a test with installing [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/), it will not affect the `EF Core` library which means it would not affect mysql function.